# How do I switch from DeliveryJob to MailDeliveryJob for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been getting this warning lately,
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sending mail with DeliveryJob and Parameterized::DeliveryJob is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use MailDeliveryJob instead.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

If you ran `rails app:update`, you should have a new file in the initializers directory.
new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb

Uncomment line 40:

`Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_job = "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob"`

This should solve the deprecation warning.