# Rails DeliveryJob deprecation warning: How to upgrade to MailDeliveryJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, deprecation-warning

I have a controller action that enqueues the delivery of an email. I wrote a test for that controller action and I've been getting a deprecation warning when I run the tests:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Sending mail with DeliveryJob and
> Parameterized::DeliveryJob is deprecated and will be removed in Rails
> 6.1. Please use MailDeliveryJob instead.

*controller:*

```
  def send_email
    SubscriptionMailer.with(user_id: @user.id).send_welcome_email.deliver_later
  end
```

*SubscriptionMailer:*

```
class SubscriptionMailer < ApplicationMailer
  helper :auxiliaries
  before_action { @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id]) }

  def send_welcome_email
    @base_email = find_base_email_or_raise("welcome_email")
    @subject = "#{@user.fname} #{@base_email.subject}"

    send_email(subject: @subject)
  end
end
```

*test:*

```
  test "#send_email should enqueue SubscriptionMailer's #send_welcome_email" do
    assert_emails 1 do
      get send_email_admin_subscriptions_activation_path(
        @user.id,
      )
    end
  end
```

How do I upgrade my App to get rid of the warnings?

I've [read about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61946252/how-do-i-switch-from-deliveryjob-to-maildeliveryjob-for-ruby-on-rails) uncommenting a line in `new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb` in different posts but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Try adding this line in `application.rb`: `config.action_mailer.delivery_job = "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob"` if you haven't already

Comment: @Deepesh Thanks, this fixed the warning message indeed. But does this affect the way the Emails are delivered in any way? Our test suite didn't fail but I'm still curious it might have other implications.

Answer (score 4):

To fix the deprecation warning add this line to `application.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_job = "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob"
```

**Source:** https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37068#issuecomment-545531362

**Q:** Does this affect the way the Emails are delivered in any way?

The parameters on the method have changed:

```
# DeliveryJob
def perform(mailer, mail_method, delivery_method, *args)

# MailDeliveryJob
def perform(mailer, mail_method, delivery_method, args:, params: nil)
```

So you might have to change the arguments in the method call wherever applicable.

You can find more details on this PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34591